# Issue while programatically creating Content Organizer Rule

Tags: content-organizer-rule

I am creating a content organizer rule using code.

My code is able to create the rule in the content organizer rule list, however its condition is not set.

I have set the condition using following code.

```
RouterRule.ConditionsString = String.Format("<Conditions>{0}</Conditions>", strConditionXML);

RouterRule.Update();

strConditionXML = Condition Column='bdf6f34h-007c-43c4-a445-847cca2f9b3c|Name|Account' Operator='equals'   Value='India-Mumbai' />
```

**The "Name" column mentioned above is Site Column in "Document Set" Content type.**

But when I execute this code, rule is created but it does not set the condition. The condition is empty.

It sets all other fields [enabled, priority, name, content type name etc.] properly.

Has anyone faced this issue earlier.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe do it like this?

Try

```
'<Conditions><Condition Column="9ce114d1-0f9d-4825-8a74-a9fc891723c2|ProjectId|Project Id" Operator="IsEqual" Value="123456" /></Conditions>'
```

For example. Also, the Field name is case sensitive so watch out!